# Test suite execution in Spring boot application with dependencies pom

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, test-suite

As I was trying out with some test suites in our app for e.g., with annotation:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ShowControllerStandaloneTest.class})
```

I found out that if we use spring-boot-dependencies, and run our application using mvn clean install, such testsuites are completely ignored. However, if we use spring-boot-starter as a parent pom, the test suites are considered during mvn clean install.

Any idea if I am missing some configuration here? I tried many plugin options with maven, didn’t help.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by renaming the testsuite classes to have the same name as source classes plus the prefix "Test" and to have a same package structure. Only then the maven install, test etc. pick this suite classes.  @SpringBoot team, is it a bug?